# .htacces RewriteRule spaces and special characters

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, special-characters

I want to redirect my old url:

```
http://www.example.com/oldurl/name-%20(page.php?a=34
```

to this url:

```
http://www.example.com/newurl/
```

Most questions about redirecting URL’s are answering parts of my question  like how to use "%20". But I don’t know how to use this all at once.

Comment: Yes I have problems with - %20 and (

Answer (score 0):

You can use this rule in root .htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^a=34$ [NC]
RewriteRule "^oldurl/name-(?:[ \s]|\x20)\(page\.php$" /newurl/? [L,NC,R=301]
```

Comment: Sorry this doesn't work, the space and everthing after the ( is a problem.

Comment: This is tested on my Apache and it works pretty well. Try updated rules.